# How can a Linux shared object detect if it is being executed on a standard or real time kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, real-time, scheduler, detect

I would like to know if some piece of C code would allow a shared object to "detect" **if it is being executed on a standard or on a real time Linux platform** (in order to act accordingly). I'm not asking for some subtle real time capability test but for something more like **simply checking if the scheduler is "marked" as real time or not** (like trusting an "auto-declared" type of scheduler, if it makes sense).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `grep 'PREEMPT ' /boot/config-$(uname -r)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question asks how an object can detect "whether or not it is being executed on a standard or on a real-time platform."  I see this as distinct from what it also somewhat ambiguously asks, which is whether or not the scheduler is "marked" as real-time or not.  The platform (first) portion asks if the real-time preemption patch has been applied to and enabled in the kernel; the scheduler class (second) portion may apply on any Linux system with the SCHED_RR and/or SCHED_FIFO classes available.  So

```
    1. Real-time platform answer:
        Look for the existence of the node /sys/kernel/realtime, available in
the real-time preemption patch since 2011 (PATCH 293/295).  If it exists, you
are running on a CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT patched kernel.  The current Linux 5.x
patch may be found at http://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/5.10/.
    
    2. Real-time scheduled on current thread answer:
        An explanation and working example are given on the
pthread_getschedparam(3) man page.  The C program example there allows
you to determine if a thread in your process is currently scheduled
with either the SCHED_RR or SCHED_FIFO policies.
```